# Adobe Animate CC JavaScript: Mouse follower is not aligned when responsive is active

Tags: javascript, adobe, code-snippets

I have started a website on Adobe Animate CC, I have done mouse follower with this code snippet:

```
    this.stage.canvas.style.cursor = "none";
    this.mouseEnabled = true;
    this.addEventListener("tick", fl_CustomMouseCursor.bind(this));

function fl_CustomMouseCursor() {
    this.plus_mc.x = stage.mouseX;
    this.plus_mc.y = stage.mouseY;
    this.black_plus_mc.x = stage.mouseX;
    this.black_plus_mc.y = stage.mouseY;
}
```

When I check on make it responsive at publish settings the follower is not aligned with mouse cursor, it only get aligned when I position the cursor at the browser top left corner then it get far as I move the cursor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution from Adobe forum by [ClayUUID](https://forums.adobe.com/people/ClayUUID):

I divided the coordinates by stage.scaleX and scaleY.

Here is the correct code to make the page responsive with cursor follower aligned:

```
this.stage.canvas.style.cursor = "none";
this.mouseEnabled = true;
this.addEventListener("tick", fl_CustomMouseCursor.bind(this));

function fl_CustomMouseCursor() {
    this.plus_mc.x = stage.mouseX / stage.scaleX;
    this.plus_mc.y = stage.mouseY / stage.scaleY;
    this.black_plus_mc.x = stage.mouseX / stage.scaleX;
    this.black_plus_mc.y = stage.mouseY / stage.scaleY;
}
```

Thank you